# Effectively handle 300 api calls | Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, api-design

I have a car table on the page and a button called refresh. When user clicks to refresh button. The controller action starts API calls first for Dealer 1 and Type 1 and Type 2 etc. till Type 30. Then it calls API for Dealer 2..

So at the end it calls 300 requests (10*30). Then I fill the below table with jquery.

```
Car     |Dealer 1|    |Dealer 2|      |Dealer 3|      |..|    |Dealer 10|
Type 1                  
Type 2                  
Type 3                  
..                  
..                  
Type 30
```

So the problem is it takes too much time. I'm thinking of using cron job. But as far as I know, I can not get return value from there. So I can image, I have to save the data to my database every 10 minutes or so, then when user clicks to refresh. It fetches from the database.

Actually, I do not need to save data to my database, the idea is just to fill the table.

Another idea, when user clicks to refresh then ruby starts cron job. It saves data after every API call. But then how can I refresh the view?

PS: I did not start coding that is why I can not share any code. But I could not find the way to do this effectively.

**EDIT:**
Alright, I get the idea. But every dealer has different api url and different type structure. For instance;

```
Dealer 1;
api.dealer1/get_prices?type1

Dealer 2;
api.dealer2/fetch_prices?type_1

Dealer 3;
api.dealer3/prices?TYPE1
..
```

that is why I was thinking of writing 10 lib modules for every dealers and loop through types array. Then return push the returned data to array and fill the table with jquery (ajax). Lastly, I can send 1 Api call per second.

**EDIT 2:**

I have watched the video on rails casts on [batch api requests](http://railscasts.com/episodes/414-batch-api-requests?autoplay=true).
He uses rack middle;

```
class BatchRequests
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env["PATH_INFO"] == "/batch"
      request = Rack::Request.new(env.deep_dup)
      responses = JSON.parse(request[:requests]).map do |override|
        process_request(env.deep_dup, override)
      end
      [200, {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}, [{responses: responses}.to_json]]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  def process_request(env, override)
    path, query = override["url"].split("?")
    env["REQUEST_METHOD"] = override["method"]
    env["PATH_INFO"] = path
    env["QUERY_STRING"] = query
    env["rack.input"] = StringIO.new(override["body"].to_s)
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
    body.close if body.respond_to? :close
    {status: status, headers: headers, body: body.join}
  end
end
```

But how can I insert the different urls here?

Comment: *"every dealer has different api url and different type structure"* -- OK, so perhaps you could make **10** (batched) API calls from the browser (which is still a lot better than 300!!). Or, you could still perform 1 API call from the browser, and then perform these 10 3rd party calls (in parallel?) from the server; mapping their responses into a consistent format.

Comment: You don't need such complicated code as the sample you've copied from rails casts, for this use case. As I answered below, *all* you need to do is send a couple of query parameters and provide a simple JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

This has got nothing to do with cron jobs. You need to reduce the total number of API calls being made, rather than focusing on how best to make the calls "in the background".

The best solution would be to fetch multiple (or even *all*) data in a single API call. This principle is called "batch queries", and it is a fundamental design principle to avoid making hundreds of individual calls like you were originally proposing.

For example, it could look something like:

```
GET /api/v1/car_prices?types[]=1&types[]=2&...&types[]=30&dealers[]=1&...&dealers[]=10

# Response:
[
  {
     type: 1,
     dealer: 1,
     price: 3000
  },
  {
     type: 1,
     dealer: 2,
     price: 2500
  },
  # ...
  {
     type: 30,
     dealer: 10,
     price: 12000
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tom. I have edited the question.